# Is Metro a good fit for apps that access the File System?

Tags: filesystems, gmail, windows-8, microsoft-metro, email-client

I understand that Metro limits the access an app has to the user's computer. Can anybody verify this, as I am considering creating an email client that will work with at least yahoo/at&t.net and gmail. Will I be able to access a user's email (assuming they provide their username and password, of course) with a Metro style app, or will I need to stick with creating an "old-fashioned" Desktop app for this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Metro can easily be used to create email clients. For something like this, you would be syncing data between the mail-server and the client.

Metro apps have limited access to the filesystem. But they can access [Application Data Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464917.aspx) and **isolatedStorage** which can be used to store data pertaining to the application offline. [**This**](http://metrostoragehelper.codeplex.com/) helper library helps store structured data in isolated storage, and might suit your needs.

For your scenario, a metro application would be a very good fit. However, the reach of metro applications will be decided by how well Windows 8 does after launch.

Comment: Thanks, DarkX; my $ is on Win8 doing very well. MS may be sluggish for awhile (profit-wise), as they have admitted, but in the long run (the marathon is more important than a sprint) I think they are going to kick booty big time. I've had Win8 installed on my laptop for less than a week, and I like it WAY better than Win7 (I never even used Vista, neither at home nor at work; we're still on XP at work).

Comment: Well, good luck! :) We're betting on Windows 8 in a big way too, hope it pays off!

Answer (score 2):

Metro applications can access the users Document Library, Picture Library, Video Library and Music Library *without* user intervention if the developer adds those capabilities to the **Package.appxmanifest** (double-click on it in Visual Studio and go to the Capabilities tab).

Even without these capabilities the app can read and write in its own local folders. And even with out these capabilities the app can prompt the user to open a file *anywhere on disk* using the FileOpenPicker. So yes, absolutely Metro can be used for an e-mail client.

For a sample of using FileOpenPicker (i.e. to add an attachment to your e-mail message) see:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/File-picker-sample-9f294cba